# How to make return button in custom keyboard swift

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I am writing a custom keyboard with Swift. I am facing some problems in making return button. The return button should change title "Return", "Done" and "Search" according to textField that user is writing.

To do it, I write like this.

```
// Syntax are not correct. I just want to explain my idea.

override fun viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
if ((textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).returnKeyType == .Default)
{
btnReturn.addTarget("addParagraph", .TouchUpInside)
btnReturn.setTitleLabel("Return", .Normal)
}
else if ((textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).returnKeyType == .Done)
{
btnReturn.addTarget("DoneKey", .TouchUpInside)
btnReturn.setTitleLabel("Done", .Normal)
}
else if ((textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).returnKeyType == .Search)
{
btnReturn.addTarget("searchKey", .TouchUpInside)
btnReturn.setTitleLabel("Search", .Normal)
}
```

Am I doing this correctly?

I can do the button to add paragraph but I don't know how to hide the keyboard when the button title is "Done" and don't know how to make search function when the button title is "Search".

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to just remove the keyboard from your view?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide this functionality since you are just building a keyboard.

It is the responsibility of the app to provide a search function or to dismiss the keyboard whenever the return key is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

for hiding keyboard:

```
func hideKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: I can't do. I think self.view.endEditing() does not work for custom keyboards. However, thanks for your help.

Comment: This dismisses the active keyboard from a ViewController containing a DocumentProxy, it won't dismiss the keyboard from within its own ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin method `dismissKeyboard()` to hide the keyboard from within the keyboard's ViewController

### Swift 4:

```
self.dismissKeyboard()
```